# RabbitMQ: d.Ack() close channel

Tags: go, rabbitmq, message-queue, rpc, channel

I am reading this [tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-go.html) about RPC with RabbitMQ

seems following line close the queue channel:

```
d.Ack()
```

Could anyone explain what `d.Ack()` is actually for? And why it happen to close the queue channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ack()](https://godoc.org/github.com/streadway/amqp#Delivery.Ack) acknowledges a delivery, and should be used when the acknowledgement mode is manual. See also Nack and Reject.

From [Consumer Acknowledgements and Publisher Confirms](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html)

> Depending on the acknowledgement mode used, RabbitMQ can consider a
>   message to be successfully delivered either immediately after it is
>   sent out (written to a TCP socket) or when an explicit ("manual")
>   client acknowledgement is received.

[Ack()](https://godoc.org/github.com/streadway/amqp#Delivery.Ack) might end up closing the channel since each message should be acknowledged not more than once, otherwise the channel gets closed due to an exception:

[AMQP basic acknowledgement:](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#basic.ack)

> A message MUST not be acknowledged more than once. The receiving peer
>   MUST validate that a non-zero delivery-tag refers to a delivered
>   message, and raise a channel exception if this is not the case.